# Formula/Proof: How many times must maxpooling (3x3 kernel, stride 2x2) be applied for a random binary mask (dxd size) to have only 1 values?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, conv-neural-network, image-processing

Given a d x d array, 1% of which contains the value 1 and all remaining locations contain the value 0. (e.g. a 128 x 128 array would have 164 values equal to 1 and 16220 values equal to 0). What would be a formula and/or proof for determining the **minimum** number of maxpooling operations with a **3x3 kernel**, **stride of 2**, and **same padding** needed to guarantee that all values in the produced array are 1.

From repeated random trials (code for reproduction below) when d is 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, or 2048, only 5 iterations of maxpooling are needed (whereas, d=32 -> 4 ops, d=16 -> 4 ops, d=8 -> 3 ops, d=4 -> 2 ops, etc.). However, a proof of mathematical certainty regarding these observations and formulation for the determination of the number of ops required for any value for d, would be beneficial.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dim = 128
numPositions = dim*dim
randQuantity = 1-0.01
num_Initial = np.floor(numPositions*randQuantity)
maxPool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')
finalIterations = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    arr_Random = tf.reshape(tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(numPositions)), (1, dim, dim, 1))
    mask_Bool = tf.greater_equal(arr_Random, num_Initial)
    mask = tf.cast(mask_Bool, dtype=tf.float32)
    numInvalid = (1.0-mask.numpy()).sum()
    iterations = 0
    while numInvalid > 0:
        mask = maxPool(mask)
        iterations+=1
        numInvalid = (1.0-mask.numpy()).sum()
    finalIterations.append(iterations)
finalIterations = np.array(finalIterations)
print('Number of Operations Required to Ensure all 1s: ', finalIterations.max())
```